# KendoUI Grid Batch Editing using ASP.NET WebAPI 3 OData Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid, odata

I want to use the Batch editing feature of KendoUI grid using ASP.NET WebAPI OData Controller. So far, I have been able to do simple CRUD operations but I cannot figure out how to do batch Create/Update/Delete operations. In batch mode, the grid send a single request for an action and sends all the affected records as a list.

For instance, the code on the server for non-batch operation looks like:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Entity entity)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        DataStore.Create(new List<Entity >() { entity});

        return Created(entity);
    }
```

And the client side transport section look like:

```
 create: {
          url: ConfigData.BaseUrl + "api/ChartOfAccounts",
          type: "post",
          dataType: 'json'
         }
```

But for Batch edit mode, the signature for server side should be something like

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post(List<Entity> entities)
```

However, I am unable to make it work. It is possible to have the above signature in ASP.NET WebAPI with OData?

Should I use custom action or is there any other way to handle this? Kendo forums are less than helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating custom action, You should consider using Batch requests. In a batch request you can combine multiple operations into one HTTP request, OData will process all requests in a single call. You don't have to change your existing OData service code, also the below action is not required.

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(List<Entity> entities)
```

To enable batch requests, just add a new route for the Batch requests as shown below -

```
HttpServer server = new HttpServer(configuration);
configuration.Routes.MapHttpBatchRoute(
    routeName:"batch",
    routeTemplate:"api/$batch",
    batchHandler:new DefaultHttpBatchHandler(server));
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("api", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Once you enable the batch requests, you can combine all entities in single POST request, OData will process them one by one. Please find more details on how the request body looks like at -
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/

Comment: If I understand it right, the batch request would combine all the requests in one single request but I want to be able to commit/rollback whole batch. Would it be possible? Also, does Kendo UI support this? So far, I only found demos of batch editing that use MVC controller at the server side

Answer (score 1):

The Grid does not come with a built-in support for batch editing when binding to OData. This can be achieved using a third-party library. For the example below I'll be using [Batch.js by Pavel Volgarev](https://github.com/volpav/batchjs).

> Note that I'm also using an experimental `transport.submit` member of the Kendo UI DataSource. This has been included for quite some time now, but will be made official in the upcoming service release in June.

A runnable sample, but with no functional back-end, is available in the [Kendo UI Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@tsvetomir/AwAce/3)

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // The methods below create an entry in the requests array for the given operation
    function queueCreated(requests, items) {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        requests.push({
          url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers",
          type: "POST",
          data: items[i]
        });

        // Assign temporary IDs as placeholders
        items[i].ContactID = kendo.guid();
      }
    }

    function queueUpdated(requests, items) {            
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        requests.push({
          url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers/" +
          items[i].CustomerID,
          type: "PUT",
          data: items[i]
        });
      }            
    }

    function queueDestroyed(requests, items) {            
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        requests.push({
          url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers/" +
          items[i].CustomerID,
          type: "DELETE"
        });
      }            
    }

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        batch: true,
        transport: {
          // Not an official feature, but it's close to being one
          submit: function(e) {
            var requests = [];

            // We get all batched operations in e.data
            queueCreated(requests, e.data.created);
            queueUpdated(requests, e.data.updated);
            queueDestroyed(requests, e.data.destroyed);

            // Check out the network tab on "Save Changes"
            $.ajaxBatch({
              // Not that this service doesn't actually support batching :(
              url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Batch",
              data: requests
            })
              .done(function() {
              e.success(e.data.created, "create");
              e.success([], "update");
              e.success([], "destroy");
            })
              .fail(function() {
              e.error({});
            });
          },
          read: function(e) {
            var data = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(e.data, "read");
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers",
              dataType: "jsonp",
              data: data,
              jsonp: "$callback"
            })
              .done(e.success)
              .fail(e.error);
          }
        },
        schema: {
          model: {
            id: "CustomerID",
            fields: {
              "ContactName": { type: "string" }
            }
          }
        },
        pageSize: 20
      },
      height: 550,
      editable: "incell",
      toolbar: ["save", "create"],
      groupable: true,
      sortable: true,
      pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
      },
      columns: [{
        field: "ContactName",
        title: "Contact Name",
        width: 240
      }, {
        field: "ContactTitle",
        title: "Contact Title"
      }, {
        field: "CompanyName",
        title: "Company Name"
      }, {
        field: "Country",
        width: 150
      }, {
        command: ["destroy"]
      }]
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Now available as part of the documentation as well http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/batch-editing-odata

Comment: I didn't get the chance to run this but would it let me perform the CRUD operations in a single transaction?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. Fingers crossed!